# How to generate "missing method" compiler error when assigning object to interface

Tags: typescript

the following TS code generates no compiler errors but fails at runtime:

```
interface IObj {
    doSmth(): void;
}

class Obj implements IObj {
    public doSmth() {
        console.log('smth');
    }
}

const o: IObj = new Obj();

const clone = { ...o };
clone.doSmth(); // Uncaught TypeError: clone.doSmth is not a function
```

I expect `const o: IObj = new Obj();` to generate an error because `doSmth` is not an own enumerable property of `o` (it is inherited from the prototype). As a result, `clone`'s type appears to be `{ doSmth(): void; }` but the actual type is `{}`.

1. How can I prevent this pitfall?
2. Is this a well-known issue?

Comment: This is a well-known issue, reported at [ms/TS#9826](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726).  The type system does not keep track of property enumerability on interfaces.  You can avoid the pitfall if you don't annotate `o` as `IObj`, since the compiler does know that `class` instance methods don't spread, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w17BXm)). But if you can't do that then this is just a hazard you'll have to deal with.  Does this fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: whoops I wrote ms/TS#9826 but meant ms/TS#9**7**26 (although the link is right).

Comment: So you opened [ms/TS#51073](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51073) after my comment? That's unfortunate.  Anyway do you want to see an answer here or not?